# How do I split my binary results into groups of four with C. The aim of the code is convert and decimal figure into binary notation

Tags: c

**For example, the binary conversion OF *233* is *11101001* and would like to transform it to something like *1110|1001***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, r, decimal, binary[20];

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n\nPLEASE ENTER ANY DECIMAL NUMBER: ");
        scanf("%d", &decimal);
        int n = decimal;

        i = 0;

        while (decimal > 0)
        {
            r = decimal % 2;
            binary[i] = r;
            decimal = decimal / 2;
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n BINARY EQUIVALENT OF %d is; ", n);

        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            printf("%d", binary[j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I bet this is a rookie question for some of you, but I could use your help, thanks

Comment: Do you want to print the first and the second nibble (4 bits) of and int variable separately? 
Justo to show in console? Or to make some logic with it?

Comment: You can always calculate the number of digits printed so far in your loop. If it's `4`, `8`, etc. then print the separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example add a condition into the second look of 'j' and after you print 4 digits you add a |

```
    for (int j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
        printf( "%d",binary[j]);
        if(j%4==0 && j!=0)
            printf("|");   
    }
```

Comment: this worked for me efficiently for what i was looking for.

Comment: good, so upvote this answer and make the question Solved, to avoid getting more replies ;)

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience but could you help me out add leading zeros to my output? i'm stuck on that part. to have something like 0010|1101

Comment: let say for example you want to have in total M digit, add a new loop from M to i that print only 0, then you put the loop that print the number

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough I was just doing this yesterday. This probably not the best way to do this but it works.

```
char* hex_to_bin (unsigned char c) {
    static char bin[10];
    strcpy (bin, "");
    char* mappings[] = {
        "0000",
        "0001",
        "0010",
        "0011",
        "0100",
        "0101",
        "0110",
        "0111",
        "1000",
        "1001",
        "1010",
        "1011",
        "1100",
        "1101",
        "1110",
        "1111"
    };

    sprintf (bin, "%s %s", mappings [(c/16) % 16], mappings[c % 16]);

    return bin;
}

void print_bin (void * ptr, size_t size) {
    int i;
    for (i = size - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        unsigned char c = ((char*)ptr)[i];
        printf ("%s ", hex_to_bin(c));
    }
}
```

To use:

```
int k = 431;
print_bin (&k, sizeof (int)); // Of course you can put any pointer here
```

It should print this:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1010 1111
```

Notice that in the `for` I iterate from the `size` to 0. This is specific for Little Endian processors. If you have a Big Endian processor that you will have to go from `0` to `size`

Comment: In a **binary** digital computer, the is no "hex internal representation. It is all binary - obviously. The name of your function does not make sense (and it way too complicated and produces a lot of overhead.

Comment: @Andrei
It works fine I guess. Just keep in mind that the operations you're doing in this code take much more time than doind bitwise operations and bit shifting so as use more memory space for variables.
Take a look at my answer using bitwise and bit shift, may be useful for you, if you're doing this.
You must just adapt for any size of int variables, but that's easy, ask me if you don't figure it out.
Night!

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to print it I suggest to make use of **bitwise** operands and **bit shift**.
Make a little research about bit shifting in C and bitwise operands (if you don't know yet of course) and then see the code and explanation below.
This is a more simplified code and more performatic too, and you will save memory with variable declarations.

**Little explanation:** 
*Bitwise operand compare each single bit of one or two variables.
Bitshift allow you to deslocate the bits of a variable to a direction the* number of times you want.

See the code bellow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    int i, decimal;
    //The mask to compare just one bit
    int mask=0b10000000;

    printf("\n\nPLEASE ENTER ANY DECIMAL NUMBER: ");
    scanf("%d", &decimal);

    //Loopping 8 bits only
    for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
        /**
        * Here you are doing the "magic", see how:
        * You're using AND bitwise operand to compare just one bit at time starting for the MSB as you can see in first mask value
        * So, first comparison with AND is you're value, for example 254, with mask shifted of 'i' bits, i value is 0 here
        * The first comparison so is: (255)11111110   -> YOUR INT VALUE
        *                           (AND)& 10000000   -> MASK
        *                          Result: 10000000   -> THE RESULT OF: decimal&mask
        * But this result in decimal is 128 and you want to show just 1 or 0, being 1 for everything that is not and 0 and 0 only for 0 results
        * Here I suggest a technique, use the NOT logical operand to invert the value logically and the do it again, as bellow:
        * !10000000 result in 0 and !0 result in 1 or 00000001, this way you can show if the bit is HIGH or DOWN.
        * Keep doing it for the other bits, let see more 2:
        * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        * Now i = 1 (second time in for loop), so mask is shifted 1 bit to right and mask is 01000000
        * Making the same comparison (255)11111110   -> YOUR INT VALUE
        *                          (AND)& 01000000   -> MASK
        *                         Result: 01000000   -> THE RESULT OF: decimal&mask
        * When you invert the result twice the result is 1 again.
        * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        * Now i = 7 (last (seventh) time in for loop), so mask is shifted 7 bits to right and mask is 00000001
        * Making the same comparison (255)11111110   -> YOUR INT VALUE
        *                          (AND)& 00000001   -> MASK
        *                         Result: 00000000   -> THE RESULT OF: decimal&mask
        * When you invert the result twice the result is now 0. Because 0&1 is 0, when inverted it is 1 and inverting again it turns 0.
        *
        */
        printf("%d", !(!(decimal&mask>>i)));
        if(i==3) printf(" "); //If it is on the fourth bit will print a space
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mask and bitwise operators shift << and AND &. If you step through the code in your debugger you will see how it works.

```
void displayBits(unsigned);

int main(int args, char *argsv[]){

   unsigned x;
   printf("Enter an unsigned integer %u\n", x );
   scanf("%u",&x);
   displayBits(x);

    return 0;
}

void displayBits(unsigned value){
    const int SHIFT = 8*sizeof(unsigned)-1;
    const unsigned MASK = 1 << SHIFT;

    printf("%u = ", value);

    unsigned c;
    for(c=1; c<=SHIFT + 1; c++){

        if(value & MASK){
            printf("%d", 1);

        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d",0);

        }
        if(c%8==0)
        printf("|");
        value <<=1;
    }
}
```